# WPF Binding on DependencyObject error

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I want to pass an object as a parameter to a Converter. Since I can't do that using a ConverterParameter, I have used a DependencyProperty instead.

Here is the code -

```
public class FilteredColumnConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
     public DataGridFilter FilterObject
     {
         get { return (DataGridFilter) GetValue(FilterObjProperty); }
         set { SetValue(FilterObjProperty, value); }
     }

     public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterObjProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register( "FilterObj",
     typeof(DataGridFilter),
     typeof(FilteredColumnConverter),
     new PropertyMetadata(null));

     // With implementations for Convert and ConvertBack
}
```

My XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources> 
     <helpers:FilteredColumnConverter x:Key="filteredColumnConverter"
              FilterObject="{Binding myFilterObj}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I'm getting the following error :

> A Binding cannot be set on the **FilterObject** property of type **FilteredColumnConverter**. A Binding can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

What seems to be the problem? I have a FilterObject is a dependency property and I have followed the naming conventions as well.

Comment: `FilterObj` should be `FilterObject`. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try register DP with name FilterObject not FilterObj

```
DependencyProperty.Register("FilterObject", ...
```